# Flip effect in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

There is a  [jQuery library](http://lab.smashup.it/flip)  to flip html content. I wonder if I can do the same thing with canvas content some way so that I have 2 sided rectangle with different content on each of its sides? Examples would be great.

Comment: Sure, show me the canvas on http://jsfiddle.net and I'll show you how to flip it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scale(1, -1)` to flip horizontally:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations#A_scale_example

Alternatively, you could just use [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#scale) to achieve the same effect.